# Oracle Functions that Take No Parameters

Tags: oracle, function

Why is it that `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `SYSDATE`, and `SYSTIMESTAMP` are called without parentheses. I understand that they take no parameters, but in other languages, you would still call the functions using parentheses. Is it the case in Oracle that any function that never takes parameters cannot be called with parentheses?

If someone could point me to the documentation on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can use Java in Oracle to write triggers, stored procedures, etc, instead of PL/SQL. Perhaps that would feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oracle is weird in many ways. It plays fast and loose with lots of things: the meaning of `NULL`, implicit data type conversions, and a whole number of other things.

Among them, as you noticed, is their inconsistent syntax for calling functions with no parameters. (For *declaring* such functions, too - see below.)

Native functions like `sysdate` and `current_timestamp`, which do not take arguments, **must** be written without parentheses. You ask for documentation... the most direct (and yet not entirely satisfactory) pointer is to the documentation of each function, where the syntax is shown very clearly **without** parentheses. What are you looking for - a separate mention in the documentation, where they state this explicitly?

Compare this with analytic functions like `rownumber()`, for example, which also do not take arguments. You **must** write them **with** empty parentheses!

Worse: For functions you write **yourself** in PL/SQL, and call from SQL statements: if the function takes no arguments, then it must be defined **without** parentheses. However, when you **invoke** it (in a `select` statement, for example) you can call it **with** *or* **without** (empty) parentheses - both syntaxes are valid. Not so, alas, with the native functions, like `sysdate`. Why? Again, a good question to ask Oracle.

It doesn't end there, either. `connect_by_root` is a "hierarchical function" (a function that can be used in hierarchical queries). It takes an argument - which can be given in parentheses (as in any normal function) or **without** parentheses! Go figure.

If you ask **WHY???** - you are not alone. I have no clue either.

Comment: I was hoping for documentation explaining the logic behind these choices, but it sounds like it's unclear and undocumented. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To further confuse things, some SQL functions have corresponding PL/SQL functions defined in the "STANDARD" PL/SQL package.  This allows functions like SYSDATE to be invoked on the right hand side of an assignment statement in a PL/SQL program block.  Because the function in the "STANDARD" package is a PL/SQL function (and not an SQL one), it can be invoked with or without parentheses.

```
DECLARE
  x DATE;
BEGIN
  x:= SYSDATE();  -- Valid
  x:= SYSDATE;    -- Also valid
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are all `Pseudocolumns` which are used in SQL or PL/SQL statements like columns but they aren't really stored on the disk. They can be thought of as special-purpose data elements within the SQL statements just as if they were part of the table.

A DML statement neither be applied on Pseudocolumns, nor user-defined they are, so they do not need to be considered as standard functions or procedures, and the style is conventionally defined by Oracle, itself.

> *By the way, this syntax(without parentheses) is valid even for a function in Oracle provided that no needs to have any parameter as
>   seems more logical rather than what other systems do.*
>
> **Oracle says :** `Parameter declarations are optional. Functions that take no parameters are written without parentheses`

Comment: Thanks, but in the 19c documentation, these are listed in the section on Datetime functions (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C), not in the section on Pseudocolumns (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pseudocolumns.html#GUID-6C65C788-76AA-4A51-B011-51D53DD2521D).

Comment: No. `sysdate` et al. are functions, not pseudocolumns. Pseudocolumns include `rowid`, `rownum`, `level` (in hierarchical queries), etc. They have (generally) different values in each row of a query where they are invoked. By contrast, functions (like `sysdate`) without arguments have the same value everywhere within a single SQL statement.

Comment: @mathguy being a function doesn't mean **not** being a pseudocolumn. Some related links : [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocolumn), [2](https://oracle-abc.wikidot.com/pseudo-column), [3](http://psoug.org/definition/SYSDATE.htm), [4](https://www.relationaldbdesign.com/oracle-sql-extensions/module3/oracle-pseudo-columns.php), [5](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/2504)

Comment: Oracle has classified SYSDATE etc as functions rather than pseudo-columns [since the get-go](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/function.htm#79218). The documentation explains the difference: *"However, functions without arguments typically return the same value for every row in the result set, whereas pseudocolumns typically return a different value for each row."*

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to your comment - I only noticed it now. APC has already provided the relevant quote from the Oracle documentation. Let me point out that none of your five links is to Oracle documentation (wonder why not). Worse, one of the links begins with "In Oracle PL/SQL, SYSDATE is ..." You may do well to avoid any source that claims to talk about Oracle SQL, yet it thinks it's called PL/SQL.